# Write integer to an array in VBA windows form

Tags: vb.net

In the code below I open a .txt file, I'm getting the itemNr from this file. Because I want to do calculations with this itemNr soon (still need to add) I want to get this ItemNr as an integer. After this I want to convert the ItemNr to a string so I can add it to my array. For some reason the convertion between integer and string isn't happening and the array is empty at the end.

```
Private materiaal As String
Private dichtheid As String
Private vorm As String
Private afmetingen As String
Private itemNr As Integer

Private gegevens() As String



Private Sub BtnDo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDo.Click
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    'Dialoogbox openen dlgOpenen komt uit toolbox
    Dim result As String
    Dim itemNr As Integer
    If dlgOpenen.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Controleer of er geen Cancel werd gekozen
        Try
            FileOpen(1, dlgOpenen.FileName, OpenMode.Input) 'bestand openen voor input
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Input(1, itemNr)
                Input(1, materiaal)
                Input(1, dichtheid)
                Input(1, vorm)
                Input(1, afmetingen)
                'calucations will be done here in future 
                result = CStr(itemNr)

                gegevens(index) = result

                index += 1

            Loop


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Fout bij openen, nr: " & Err.Number & " type: " & ex.GetType.ToString)
        Finally
            FileClose(1)
        End Try
    End If


    Dim bestandsnaam As String
    If dlgBewaren.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 'de gebruiker wil bewaren
        bestandsnaam = dlgBewaren.FileName 'ingegeven bestandsnaam
        Try
            FileOpen(2, bestandsnaam, OpenMode.Output)
            PrintLine(2, gegevens)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Fout bij schrijven, nr: " & Err.Number & " type: " & ex.GetType.ToString)
        Finally
            FileClose(1)
        End Try
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What a weird mix of old and new code.  Was this a conversion of an old VB6 program?

You shouldn't mix the Try/Catch model with the old Err object, those two things shouldn't go together.

Instead of an array:

```
Private gegevens() As String
```

Change to a [List(Of String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Private gegevens As New List(Of String)
```

Then you can simply add things to it and it will grow automatically.

Writing to the new file can be greatly simplified by using [File.WriteAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_String___).

Consider moving to the newer [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) model for reading the file.  I left the code as is, as I don't remember all the details about how the legacy `Input()` function works.

Instead of MsgBox, use the newer [MessageBox.Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8).

Here's the modified code:

```
Private materiaal As String
Private dichtheid As String
Private vorm As String
Private afmetingen As String
Private itemNr As Integer

Private gegevens As New List(Of String)

Private Sub BtnDo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDo.Click
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    'Dialoogbox openen dlgOpenen komt uit toolbox
    Dim result As String
    Dim itemNr As Integer
    If dlgOpenen.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Controleer of er geen Cancel werd gekozen
        Try
            FileOpen(1, dlgOpenen.FileName, OpenMode.Input) 'bestand openen voor input
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Input(1, itemNr)
                Input(1, materiaal)
                Input(1, dichtheid)
                Input(1, vorm)
                Input(1, afmetingen)

                'calucations will be done here in future 
                result = CStr(itemNr)

                gegevens.Add(result)
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Fout bij openen: " & ex.ToString)
        Finally
            FileClose(1)
        End Try
    End If

    Dim bestandsnaam As String
    If dlgBewaren.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 'de gebruiker wil bewaren
        bestandsnaam = dlgBewaren.FileName 'ingegeven bestandsnaam
        Try
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(bestandsnaam, gegevens)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Fout bij schrijven: " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```